# How to check the packets is actually coming thru the VPN Tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, strongswan

I have setup up a VPN server with strongswan.
My VPN is coming up, but I want to make sure packets are actually going through the tunnel.

Are there some commands to check this on the VPN server/Strongswan ?

Comment: Ping something on the other side?

Comment: I have only 1 interface on the vpn server

Comment: Nothing on the other side of the VPN? i.e. something to talk to/from?

Comment: Am trying to access some website on other end
but traffic is not going thru
So want to check if i can see packets are coming thru tunnel or not
ping will not help me as mine is a on-demand vpn for http/s traffic

Answer (score 0):

You could do a tcpdump on the outside interface and see if there are encrypted or unencrypted packets coming in.

Comment: Would tcpdump shows encrypted packets as well ?

Comment: yes, sure. It shows all the packets coming in and going out of the interface.

Comment: am accessing login.salesforce.com ...ok
and i have put a filter on the vpn server - tcpdump -i bond0 -n dst net 204.14 -vv

But i do not see any packets